# Snakemake & singularity, making different mounts available to each rule

Tags: snakemake, singularity-container

I have been using singularity with some of my workflows and it works great so far. I have a question about binding directories. I can pass singularity arguments when running the snakemake workflow like:

`snakemake --use-singularity --singularity-args "-B /path/outside/container/:/path/inside/container/"`

Is there a way to have binds be rule specific?

Thanks.